# Php not working with SQL database and inserting values

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle, insert

Hi if you go to http://www.deakin.edu.au/~jrhaywar/SIT104/Contact.php you will find the webpage workings (or not working in this case). What i wish for the program to do is show the form if there is not post action however if there is a post action to replace the form entries with the details of the forms. As Well as add the details to the SQL Database. However it now just repeats the tables and forms multiple times. Could someone look at this quickly for me and try to help fix the problem? 
Cheers 
Jesse,

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Assignment 1 - SIT 104 - 214151511</title>
<!--This is where the Classes and Division Styles are setup for recall later in the code-->
<style type="text/css">

#Wrapper{
        Background:url(images/Crests.png);
        background-size:26%;
        background-position:top 6px;
        height:100%;
}

#NavBar{
    Height:26%;
    Border:groove Gold 6px;

}

#Body{
            Height:76%;
            border:groove Gold 6px;
            text-align:center;

    }

#Footer{
            Height:26%;
            background:#999;
            Border:groove gold 6px;

    }
</style>


</head>

<body>
<!-- This is the php to setup the connection to the oracle database needed to record information and to display reciept -->

<?php

/* Set oracle user login and password info */
$dbuser = "jrhaywar"; /* your deakin login */
$dbpass = "haybreaker"; /* your oracle access password */
$db = "SSID";
$connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

if (!$connect) {
echo "An error occurred connecting to the database";
exit;
}

/* build sql statement using form data */
$query = "SELECT * FROM sit104Items";
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $name = $POST_['Name'];
    $phone = $POST_['Phone'];
    $email = $POST_['Email'];
    $reason = $POST_['Reason'];
    $message = $POST_['Message'];       

    $insert = $insert = "INSERT INTO ContactUs VALUES     ('$name','$phone','$email','$reason','$message')";
    $Insert = OCIParse($connect, $insert);
    }
    /* check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them */
    $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);
    //echo "SQL: $query<br>";
    if(!$stmt) {
    echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
    exit;
    }
    OCIExecute($stmt);

    ?>

<!--This is the beggining of the code that will be shown in the browser Starting with the wrapper and     Navigation bar and then continuing with the "body" division and ended by the footer-->
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="NavBar">
 <table style="width:100%" height="10%" bgcolor="#CCFF00">
  <tr>
     <td width="26%" align="center" ><a link href="ass1.htm"><b>Home Page</b></a></td>
    <td width="26%" align="center"><a link href="Items.php"><b>Items</b></a></td>
    <td width="26%" align="center" ><a link href="FAQ.html"><b>FAQ/HELP</b></a></td>
    <td width="26%" align="center" ><a link href="Contact.html"><b>Contact Us</b></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="Body">
<font size="6" face="Serpentine Bold" color="lime" ><b>
Welcome to the Order Page, please order what you wish!</b>
<hr/>
</font>
<?php
while(OCIFetch($stmt)){
/*Calculate what to do and show if Post is found*/
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    echo('<table align="center" bgcolor="#00FF66" border="4" bordercolor="black" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td  colspan="4" bgcolor="#00FFCC"><b>Personal and Delivery Details</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="6%" >Name:</td>
        <td width="46%" >');
    $fg1 = OCIResult($stmt, "NAME");
    echo $fg1;
    echo('</td>
        <td width="6%" >Phone Number:</td>
        <td width="46%" >');
    $fg2 = OCIResult($stmt, "PHONE");
    echo $fg2;
    echo('</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td width="10%">E-mail</td>
            <td width="80%" colspan="3">');
    $fg3 = OCIResult($stmt, "EMAIL");
    echo $fg3;
    echo('</td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <table align="center" bgcolor="#00FF66" border="4" bordercolor="black" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#00FFCC" ><b>Message</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">Reason for message:</td>
        <td width="90%">');
    $fg4 = OCIResult($stmt, "REASON");
    echo $fg4;
    echo('</tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">Type Message Here: </td>
        <td width="90%">
    ');
    $fg5 = OCIResult($stmt, "MESSAGE");
    echo $fg5;
    echo('</td>
    </tr>
    </table>');


} /*End of the First If. So now compute what to do if post isn't used */


else


{
    echo('
<form name="ContactForm" onSubmit="Contact.php" >
<table align="center" bgcolor="#00FF66" border="4" bordercolor="black" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td  colspan="4" bgcolor="#00FFCC"><b>Personal and Delivery Details</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="6%" >Name:</td>
    <td width="46%" ><input Type="text" name="Name" style="width:86%"/></td>
    <td width="6%" >Phone Number:</td>
    <td width="46%" ><input type="text" Name="Phone" style="width:86%"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="10%">E-mail</td>
    <td width="80%" colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Email" style="width:30%" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<hr/>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#00FF66" border="4" bordercolor="black" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#00FFCC" ><b>Message</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Reason for message:</td>
    <td width="90%"><select name="Reason">
                    <option value="General Enquiry" >General Enquiry</option>
                    <option value="Returning Item" >Returning Item</option>
                    <option value="Missing Item" >Missing Item</option>
                    <option value="Price Negotiation">Price Negotiation</option>
                    </select>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Type Message Here: </td>
    <td width="90%"><textarea name="Message"  rows="5" style="width:90%;height:100%;"></textarea>            </td>
</tr>
</table>


<input type="submit" value="Send Message" style="width:95%; height:35px; margin-top:10px; background-    color:#0F0"/>

</form>
');}
}
OCILogOff($connect);
?>

 <br/>

</div>

<div id="Footer">

Links:<br/>
<a href="ass1.htm">Home</a><br/>
<a href="Items.php">Items</a><br/>
<a href="Order.html">Order Form</a><br/>
<a href="FAQ.html">faq/help</a><br/>
<a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a><hr/>

<p align="left">
©Deakin University, School of Information Technology. This web page has been developed as a student assignment for the unit SIT104: Introduction to Web Development. Therefore it is not part of the         University's authorised web site. DO NOT USE THE INFORMATION CONTAINED ON THIS WEB PAGE IN ANY WAY
</p>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see while viewing i overlooked the double insert, And i shouldn't need to give column name should i if all collumns are being filled in the correct order by the values?-- Even with those two things edited i still have the same problem.

Comment: Hi, will try that out, Ive fixed the first error of there being multiple rows by removing the While(OCIFetch($stmt)){... as that isn't going to give me the result i need, the only thing now is getting it to replace the form entries with the details just entered.

Comment: I've Just realized that the code you just sent me is already      in there  as if(!$stmt) {
        echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
        exit;
        }